# Is possible get the orientation of an image generated by the php gd in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, gd

There's any ways for detect the angle/orientation of an image generated by php gd in javascript?

I would need something like this

```
var angle = getImgData(document.getElementById('img1')).getOrientation();
```